# "Unable to resolve module path" in React Native

Tags: react-native

After adding a new dependency, I get the error message "Unable to resolve module path" in a red screen in my React Native app. I've tried clearing the cache as the screen instructs.

*(question is brief as I'm answering it myself)*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error message:

> Unable to resolve module path

Should really be:

> Unable to resolve module "path"

`path` is the name of the module it can't load! I was reading the error message as "can't resolve a path to the module".

So the root cause is, the file it lists in the error message is importing the native Node module `path`, which isn't available on React Native.

**The solution is to [`npm install -D path`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path), which is a replica implementation.**

Comment: You can also add the "path" polyfill for "react-native" using the "path-browserify".

Answer (score 10):

Any imports from `@babel/core` package is causing this error.

Some code editors are inserting the import line automatically.

For example, `import { types } from '@babel/core'` is inserted by Visual Studio Code when you enter `types`.

If you remove the imports from `@babel/core` in the codes, it will be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Quote from ***chronikum*** on react-native github issues for future readers

> Just check if you somewhere accidentally imported something from
>   @babel/core.

Here is the original link

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27522#issuecomment-568306279

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers are really helpful, I found that the problem in my case was that the macros plugin was missing in my babel configuration file.

This is what I had in my `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
};
```

After adding the macros plugin

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["macros"],
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
};
```

If you get this error, most like you are missing a plugin in your babel config.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my issue by the below steps.

Read the error message carefully, the error is node modules path(mentioned as NO: 1 in below image). In my case, I have the "just-cli/" module (Mentioned NO: 2).
search the module (just-cli) you have imported somewhere in your project and just Remove it. The problem will be solved.

[image]