# Unable to resolve module util from node_modules\uuidv4\build\lib\uuidv4.js: util could not be found within the project

Tags: react-native

I've updated my modules in the package.json and I'm now getting the error "Unable to resolve module util from node_modules\uuidv4\build\lib\uuidv4.js: util could not be found within the project."

Of the steps below, I've done #2. I'm not using watchman for #1, I'm using npm instead of yarn for #3, and I don't know what path #4 is referring to.  Here is my full output.

PS C:\Dev\myProj> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

(node:16148) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Welcome to React Native!
Learn once, write anywhere

error Unable to resolve module `util` from `node_modules\uuidv4\build\lib\uuidv4.js`: util could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
   Error: Unable to resolve module `util` from `node_modules\uuidv4\build\lib\uuidv4.js`: util could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
   at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Dev\myProj\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
   at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Dev\myProj\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
   at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Dev\myProj\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
   at Object.resolve (C:\Dev\myProj\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
   at C:\Dev\myProj\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:434:31
   at Array.map ()
   at resolveDependencies (C:\Dev\myProj\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
   at C:\Dev\myProj\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
   at Generator.next ()
   at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Dev\myProj\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "myproj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "prettier": "prettier --write '*.js' 'src/**/*.js'",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "android": " cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^8.3.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.7.1",
    "@skele/components": "^1.0.0-alpha.40",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-blur": "^8.1.2",
    "expo-camera": "^8.3.1",
    "expo-constants": "~9.1.1",
    "expo-facebook": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-file-system": "^9.1.0",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^1.1.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-localization": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-location": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-permissions": "^9.1.0",
    "firebase": "7.18.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "i18n-js": "^3.7.1",
    "invert-color": "^2.0.0",
    "jest-haste-map": "^26.3.0",
    "jest-serializer": "^26.3.0",
    "jest-worker": "^26.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "mobx": "^5.15.6",
    "mobx-react": "^6.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "oauth-1.0a": "^2.2.6",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-appearance": "~0.3.4",
    "react-native-autogrow-textinput": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-button": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-dialog-input": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.32.2",
    "react-native-image-filter-kit": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.3",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-view": "0.0.14",
    "react-native-keyboard-input": "^6.0.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-tracking-view": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-patch": "git+https://github.com/HarvestProfit/react-native-modal-patch.git",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.9",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-search-box": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-nightly.5",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.10.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "7.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.7.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^4.0.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "7.7.0",
    "jest": "^26.4.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.62.0",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: This type of problem has solved by  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66852280/11752083

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to roll back:

"uuidv4": "^5.0.1"

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a lot of time. The only difference is I had to roll way back to 3.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers provided here worked for me. I tried

- Reverting to "uuidv4": "^5.0.1"
- Reverting to "uuidv4": "^3.0.1"
- Deliting the node_modules folder and then running `npm i`

What fixed it for me was using this UUID generation instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-uuid

Answer (score 1):

Search somewhere you have imported "uuidv4" in your project and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the ***node-modules*** folder from your project and after that ****run npm-install**** for generating it again. This worked for me.

Comment: @ChrisEaheart Could this helps you? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58731328)

Answer (score 0):

Then import `uuidv4` from `uuid` library

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
```

Inside function:

```
setTodo(prevTodo => {
`return [...prevTodo,{id:uuidv4(), name: name, complete:false}]
})
```